# Convert String of generated by LocalDateTime.now() to the its data type

Tags: java, date, converters

I'm trying to convert a String with a value of a `LocalDateTime` and convert it to the `LocalDateTime` data type.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
```

and I've also tried using this:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime);
```

But gets the same parsing error

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-09-12T11:14:38.176906Z' could not be parsed at index 10
```

Value of the dateTime variable is (Generated before using LocalDateTime.now())

```
2019-09-12T11:14:38.176906Z
```

Comment: Using a pattern that __matches__ your date String would be helpful here.

Comment: isn't there a `T` between date and time in the String that is not matched in the pattern (expects empty space)? `2019-09-12T11` cannot be matched by `yyyy-MM-dd HH` (at index 10 as reported in Exception)

Comment: @Tom it is generated from `LocalDateTime.now()` directly. I'm not quite sure what is the pattern on that.

Comment: Your string represents an `Instant` (or `OffsetDateTime`), not a `LocalDateTime`. The `Z` at the end stands  for the UTC offset (`+00:00`). `LocalDateTime` will also never produce a value with a `Z` at the end.

Comment: Your String date is generated by `LocalDateTime.now()`, yes, but your pattern isn't and the most obvious different is the letter `T`. You've ignored that in your pattern.

Comment: @Tom I've traced the code. I apologize. Someone generated teh LocalDateTime but when passing to my function, the changed it to `ISO_INSTANT` string. Please check the edited code above.

Comment: No you misunderstood me. You String `2019-09-12T11:14:38.176906Z` is fine. Your pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX` is wrong. So it is not really important how you generated your String, because that part is fine and working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the standard `DateTimeFormatter`s:
`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` or `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`
(your `String` appears to be an offset from UTC).

For the output, you can then use which one you want:

```
String datetime = "2019-09-12T11:14:38.176906Z";
OffsetDateTime ldt = OffsetDateTime.parse(datetime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
```

Output in this example is: `2019-09-12 11:14:38`.

Comment: `ldt`.format() generates a `String` and not a `LocalDateTime` data type

Comment: Yes, that one is for output... Have a look at the `DateTimeFormatter` used in `OffsetDateTime.parse(...)`. You can use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` there, too. Your date time `String` represents a time calculated by an offset from UTC. You can convert is to a `LocalDateTime`, if you want to.